# A problem about Binomial Converges to Poisson.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

We know that the Poisson distribution as the limit of binomial as n goes to infinity but also p goes to zero in such a way that np goes to $\lambda $.For P(X = x) write down the binomial formula and the Poisson formula that it converges to. For n = 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000 (as many as needed) and $\lambda = 4$ and for each of x = 2, 4 and 8, make a table where n gets big and np is fixed at $\lambda $ to show that this convergence takes place.

I was wondering how to show it by using table. for example for x=2, I keep increasing the value of n and plug in to Binomial and check values are same as in Poisson. am I in right track ? Please Help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Comment:** Such tables can be made in R, with refinements by people more clever at
formatting than I. Here is some crude code and the results of it:

```
MAT = matrix(0, nrow=8, ncol=11)
lam = 4; n = c(5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000)
p = lam/n
k = 0:10
for (i in 1:7) { MAT[i,] = dbinom(k, n[i], p[i]) }
MAT[8,] = dpois(k, lam)
cbind(c(n,Inf), round(MAT,4))

     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]  [,10]  [,11]  [,12]
[1,]    5 0.0003 0.0064 0.0512 0.2048 0.4096 0.3277 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
[2,]   10 0.0060 0.0403 0.1209 0.2150 0.2508 0.2007 0.1115 0.0425 0.0106 0.0016 0.0001
[3,]   50 0.0155 0.0672 0.1433 0.1993 0.2037 0.1629 0.1063 0.0581 0.0271 0.0110 0.0039
[4,]  100 0.0169 0.0703 0.1450 0.1973 0.1994 0.1595 0.1052 0.0589 0.0285 0.0121 0.0046
[5,]  500 0.0180 0.0727 0.1462 0.1958 0.1962 0.1569 0.1044 0.0594 0.0295 0.0130 0.0052
[6,] 1000 0.0182 0.0730 0.1464 0.1956 0.1958 0.1566 0.1043 0.0595 0.0297 0.0131 0.0052
[7,] 5000 0.0183 0.0732 0.1465 0.1954 0.1954 0.1564 0.1042 0.0595 0.0297 0.0132 0.0053
[8,]  Inf 0.0183 0.0733 0.1465 0.1954 0.1954 0.1563 0.1042 0.0595 0.0298 0.0132 0.0053
```

The columns, from `[2]` on, are for $k = 0, 1, \dots, 10.$ The first column
shows values of $n$ for Binomial, except that the last row `Inf` is for
$Pois(\lambda=4).$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, choose values of $n$ and show that

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf P(X_n = 0) = e^{-4} \approx 0.0183$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf P(X_n = 1) = 4 e^{-4} \approx 0.0731$

et cetera.

$$\begin{array}{c|rr} n & 5 & 10 & 50 & 100 & 1000 & 5000 
\\ p & .8 & .4 & .08 & .04 & 0.008
 & 0.004
\\\hline \binom n 0 p^0(1-p)^n & 0.00032 & 0.00605 & 0.0155 &0.0169 & 0.0182 & 0.0183
\\ \binom n 1 p^1(1-p)^{n-1} & 0.0064 & 0.0403 & 0.0672 & \ddots
\\ \binom n 2 p^2(1-p)^{n-2}
\\ \vdots
\end{array}$$

I've only done this to three decimal places, you might want to round to more significant figures.